# NativeDragEvent for drag and drop from the desktop not called Flashbuilder debugger

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flash-builder

If I build my mxml file to an .air application, NativeDragEvent works like a charm. However, I would like to be able to debug this feature from Flashbuilder. From Flashbuilder, the NativeDragEvents are not called. Any workaround?

Comment: I don't understand.  Did you launch your AIR app in debug mode using Flash Builder?

Comment: If I build the air app and run it from the desktop it works perfecly. When I run if from Flex debugger, the native drag events are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Do not use Flash builder as Administrator user (Windows 7)

Comment: Thanks for this. This solved a similar problem I was having with FlashDevelop.